# matplotlib and tkinter: fixed figure size / scrolling or zooming on window resize

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

i want to show a figure using matplotlib in a tkinter window. This works fine using `FigureCanvasTkAgg`, but it ignores my proposed `figsize`

Is it omehow possible to show this plot in such a way that it preserves its `figsize`, no matter the window size? So when it is smaller than the window size (or its allocated space in a grid) than it should be centered in the middle, when its larger scroll bars should appear, but it should never be resized.

Additionally I would love to be able to "zoom in" to that Canvas, so again without changing the size of the plot itself, just zooming in and out, as if it would be a picture (thus resizing all text etc accordingly).

For both of these questions I have no idea where to start, since I have little experience with tkinter and would love some input or help.

Here i have a minimal working example which shows how it ignores the `figsize`:

```
from tkinter import *

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


root = Tk()
root.title('Plotviewer 0.2a')
root.geometry('800x500')


def graph():
    # Data for plotting
    t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
    s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10), dpi=80)
    ax.plot(t, s)

    ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
           title='About as simple as it gets, folks')
    ax.grid()

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root, resize_callback=None)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row="0", column="1", sticky="NEWS")



button = Button(root, text="Graph", command=graph)
button.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.columnconfigure(0, weight="0")
root.columnconfigure(1, weight="1")
root.rowconfigure(0, weight="1")

graph()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The ` sticky="NEWS"` argument is the part that's overriding your figure size setting. Adding scrollbars dynamically and adding the zoom option are fairly complex requests.

Comment: thanks, this worked mostly. if the window is bigger then the plot it looks how i wanted it, but if the window is smaller the size changes again. and regarding scroll bars and zoom: how would you go on about these? any starting point for these?